# How to retrieve data on select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make it so if I chose `black` in the `select` then the `src` attribute will be read? What do I need to change?

```
$('.select').click(function() {
    var lalala = $(this).val(); 
    $("#gallery .imgsx").css('opacity', '0.5');
    $(".loading").css('opacity', '1');
    $("#gallery .imgsx").on("load", function() {
        $("#gallery .imgsx").css('opacity', '1');
        $(".loading").css('opacity', '0');
    }).attr("src", lalala);
});
```

```html
<select name="quantity[]" class="quantity small select" id="quantity-select">
    <?php
        if (!$black == '') { echo "<option value='black' src='/image/thumb/Untitled-1.jpg'>Black</option>"; }
        if (!$gray == '') { echo "<option value='gray' src='/image/thumb/Untitled-2.jpg'>Gray</option>"; }
        if (!$silver == '') { echo "<option value='silver' src='/image/thumb/Untitled-3.jpg'>Silver</option>"; }
        if (!$white == '') { echo "<option value='white' src='/image/thumb/Untitled-4.jpg'>White</option>"; }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Wooo downvotes, someone should explain to OP that mixing php code inside javascript code does not make sense, instead ajax query should done

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak there is no PHP-Code inside javascript. And using php inside HTML is not the worst thing to do unless you're using a template engine.
But the question itself could be more clear and specific.

Comment: @empiric  I suppose election done with php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `option:selected` selector to find selected option:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.select').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('pre').html($this.find('option:selected').attr('src'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="quantity[]" class="quantity small select" id="quantity-select">
    <option value='black' src='/image/thumb/Untitled-1.jpg'>Black</option>
    <option value='gray' src='/image/thumb/Untitled-2.jpg'>Gray</option>
    <option value='silver' src='/image/thumb/Untitled-3.jpg'>Silver</option>
    <option value='white' src='/image/thumb/Untitled-4.jpg'>White</option>
</select>
<pre>
  
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `src` is not a valid attribute for an `option` element. To store custom data in an element use a `data-*` attribute, like this:

```
<select name="quantity[]" class="quantity small select" id="quantity-select">
    <?php
        if (!$black == '') { echo "<option value='black' data-src='/image/thumb/Untitled-1.jpg'>Black</option>"; }
        if (!$gray == '') { echo "<option value='gray' data-src='/image/thumb/Untitled-2.jpg'>Gray</option>"; }
        if (!$silver == '') { echo "<option value='silver' data-src='/image/thumb/Untitled-3.jpg'>Silver</option>"; }
        if (!$white == '') { echo "<option value='white' data-src='/image/thumb/Untitled-4.jpg'>White</option>"; }
    ?>
</select>
```

Then in your JS you should hook to the `change` event of the `select` so that the code works for those who navigate by keyboard as well as the mouse. You can also retrieve the data attribute by using the `option:selected` selector and `data()`. You also only need to attach the `load()` event to the `img` once. Try this:

```
$('.select').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    var src = $(this).find('option:selected').data('src');

    $("#gallery .imgsx").prop('src', src).css('opacity', '0.5');
    $(".loading").css('opacity', '1');
});

$("#gallery .imgsx").on("load", function() {
    $("#gallery .imgsx").css('opacity', '1');
    $(".loading").css('opacity', '0');
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `$('.select').change(...);` rather than `click`?

Comment: @JoshHarrison yes - forgot to change that. Thanks.